# Open windows form (MDI) in thread c#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

I am having a MDI form, now clicking on the menu in MDI form, I am opening other forms in `PnlView` (Panel), this acts as container for forms.

What I am thinking is, when the application loads, it opens a default form.
At this point I want to open all forms, but as opening all forms at a time will hamper the performance, other forms opening should run in different thread. Then if all forms are open then user can switch between forms quickly.

```
   private bool IsFormAlreadyOpen(ControlItem _item)
    {
       bool reutrnValue = false;
       foreach (Control ctrl in PnlView.Controls)
       {
          if (ctrl.Name.ToLower() == _item.Control.Name.ToLower())
          {
             reutrnValue = true;
             break;
          }
       }
       return reutrnValue;
    }


This is the function which checks if form is already opened or not. So this will get all the forms open and will just bring that form to front.

Can anyone helps me with opening form in thread so that it will not impact the performance.  
I hope this makes sense.

---------------------------------------------------------------------

     private void MdiForm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
  OpenFirstForm(); //This ospens a default form, form name frmDefault
         bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
                bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
                bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
                bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
                bw.RunWorkerAsync();
            }

            private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                //this.tbProgress.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");
            }

            private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
            {
                BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

                for (int i = 1; (i <= 2); i++)
                {
                    if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
                        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                       OpenForms(form1);
                       OpenForms(form2);
                        worker.ReportProgress((i * 10));
                    }
                }
            }
```

It throws an exception,

### Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

Getting below exception,
 No Overload 'OpenForm' matches delegate MethodInvoker

```
       this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(OpenForm),new object[] { Keys.F12, Keys.Alt });

    private void OpenForm(Keys keyPressed, Keys modifier)
    {
---------------------------
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea to me. Suppose you have 50 forms and the user only opens 10 of them. What a waste of cpu and memory. Also why open an mdi form in a panel ?

Comment: Not opening MDI in panel. Panel is inside MDI. opening child forms in panel

Comment: Now lets suppose only 5 forms I need to keep open at start. Fix 5 forms on start. Is this suitable?

Comment: If there are forms that are very frequently opened than you could consider keeping them open, but only if they require lots of time to open. Else there is no use for this. Also keeping them open means extra code to update the contents when a user pulls it back to visible.

Comment: What do you mean with 'opening child forms in panel' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access a control instantiated in one thread from another thread. Use the following code snippet to solve your issue at hand:

```
// Paste this snippet in the beginning of your method
if (InvokeRequired)
{
   this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(/*Enter the name of your method here*/));
   return;
}
// Method code goes here ......

/*
    Example:
    private void SomeMethod(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       if (InvokeRequired)
       {
         this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(SomeMethod)); // Name of current method is 'SomeMethod'
         return;
       }
       // Code continues here
       int x,y,z;
       // Do something .....
    }
*/
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Johny Bravo Remove the part ",new object[] { Keys.F12, Keys.Alt }" from your code. You do not have to specify the keys there.

Comment: this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(OpenForm));  --Still the error is same, no overload....

Comment: @Johny Bravo And if that too doesn't function, there is something wrong with your 'OpenForm' method.

Comment: If I create a parameterless method, it works,    private void DoWork(), I can call this.But my original method is accepting two parameters.

Comment: @Johny Bravo I speculated that all your methods were event handlers. For methods with parameters, you need to pass a delegate as the parameter of 'MethodInvoker' instead of method name as follows:  delegate { <method name>(<parameters>); }